# Silverlight Design Architecture

Tags: silverlight

Is there a good Silverlight Design Architecture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Prism](http://www.codeplex.com/CompositeWPF) it was originally designed for WPF but there is now a Silverlight release.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is [Caliburn](http://www.codeplex.com/caliburn/), an "Application Framework for Silverlight and WPF".

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Rocky Lhotka's CSLA.NET for Silverlight - [CslaLight](http://www.lhotka.net/cslalight/Default.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Soon, Microsoft will be releasing a new version of Prism (though unlike the earlier answer), the Silverlight version of Prism is just a proof of concept. The PnP team hope to have a full release in the next couple of months. The prevailing story today is to use the same MVVM pattern that WPF has had success with (searching for Silverlight and MVVM will yield a lot of info).